# Can someone expand what is meant by 'configure' and 'build' with CMake files

Tags: build, cmake, configure

I am downloading this code from GitHub ([subdivision-regression](https://github.com/rstebbing/subdivision-regression)), and am getting stuck following the instructions:

```
To build doosabin_regression:

    Run CMake with an out of source build.
    Set COMMON_CPP_INCLUDE_DIR to the full path to rstebbing/common/cpp.
    Set DOOSABIN_INCLUDE_DIR to the full path to rstebbing/subdivision/cpp/doosabin/include.
    Set Ceres_DIR to the directory containing CeresConfig.cmake.
    Set GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIR, GFLAGS_LIBRARY and RAPID_JSON_INCLUDE_DIR. (Add -std=c++11 to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS if compiling with gcc.)
    Configure.
    Build.
```

I have edited the `CMakeLists.txt` file to put the correct paths in. I then created a new directory called `subdivision-regression-bin` and ran:

```
cmake ../subdivision-regression/src
```

It completes this and displays:

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/hert5584/RStebbing/subdivision-regression-bin
```

However, when I try and run the example code, it cannot find the files listed in `CMakeLists.txt` (I know they are the right paths as otherwise CMake does not run).

I have tried running:

```
sudo make install
```

But get the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'. Stop.
```

Any ideas why this isn't working? Have the above steps Configured and Built the files?

Comment: The instructions don't ask you to **install** the project, they ask only to *configure* and *build* it. But `make install` actually *installs* the project. For *build* the project use plain `make`. Difference between "build" and "install" is not a CMake-specific, almost any build system describes these stages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordered CMake idiom to understand is:

1. The **Configure** step
2. The **Generate** step (This is often subsumed in the Configure step, and not mentioned explicitly, as in this case.)
3. The **Build** step (in which you actually compile/link your code into libraries/executables)

Take a look at this [resource](https://preshing.com/20170511/how-to-build-a-cmake-based-project/#the-configure-and-generate-steps) for information about the *configure* and *generate* stages.

You didn't appear to perform the steps to set CMake cache variables. For these you have to use CMake command line [options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#options) (`-D` specifically). So run CMake as something like this instead to set all six variables:

```
cmake -DCOMMON_CPP_INCLUDE_DIR=/rstebbing/common/cp -DDOOSABIN_INCLUDE_DIR=...[More CMake Cache variables]...  ../subdivision-regression/src
```

For building, try just running `make` without `sudo` or `install`:

```
make
```

Comment: `sudo` is usually needed for *installing* (`make install`), but is rarely needed for just *building*.

Comment: Thank you! I was manually editing the CMakeList.txt not doing it with the command! All working now